# How to Update one Sharepoint List (calendar) from Another (custom)?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

As part of an EvenReceiver the itemAdded on a custom List (source) creates a Calendar entry in another List (target).

I now want to add an itemUpdated event so that when the the source List is updated the change is filtered through to the target List.

I am using c# in Visual Studio to develop the Event Receiver.

Can anyone please advise the best way to do this and how I create the link between the two Lists to ensure I can update from source to target?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to udpate the target list yourself...

```
var sourceItem = this.properties.ListItem;

//you can use other properties to search for the item in the targetlist aswell
string query = string.Format("<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value></Eq></Where>", sourceItem.Title);

var spQuery = new SPQuery() { Query = query };
var foundItems = targetList.GetItems(spQuery);

if(foundItems.Count == 1)
{
    var foundItem = foundItems[0];

    //update the properties you want
    foundItem["Property1"] = sourceItem["Property1"];
    foundItem["Property2"] = sourceItem["Property2"];
    foundItem["Property3"] = sourceItem["Property3"];

    foundItem.Update();
}
```

Note that this piece of code is straight out of my head & untested ;-)